# How do I get out of this infinite loop where the user says yes and it goes back up to the first while loop until the user says no?

Tags: java

I'm trying to prompt the user to enter a number and then afterwards ask them if they want to enter another. If yes then they restart the first while loop and if no then they exit to print the numbers they selected.

However it seems that no matter what I do, I cannot get out of the first loop. It just keeps repeating number over and over.

I tried putting userInput = "y", break, and continue at the end of where valid= true; currently is and they all produce the same result.

Being stuck in an infinite loop.

```
ArrayList<Integer> inputs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
System.out.println("Enter some numbers: ");

   String userInput = "y"; 
    boolean valid = false;

    do {
        while (scnr.hasNextInt()) {
           inputs.add(scnr.nextInt());
           System.out.println("Would you like to enter another?");
           valid = true;
           }
           System.out.println(inputs);

    } while (!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));
```

Comment: Where are you reading "y/n"? You never update userInput with the user provided response.

Comment: Do you mean to add an userInput = scnr.nextLine(); after "Would you like to enter another?" If so, it still reads as stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not breaking out of the inner loop. Here how I would write the same code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadNumbers {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> inputs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("Enter some numbers: ");
    try (Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in)) {
      do {
        inputs.add(scnr.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Would you like to enter another y/n?");
      } while (scnr.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    }
    System.out.println(inputs);
  }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Enter some numbers: 
14
Would you like to enter another y/n?
y
15
Would you like to enter another y/n?
y
17
Would you like to enter another y/n?
y
44
Would you like to enter another y/n?
n
[14, 15, 17, 44]
```

The other way to read numbers is to read several from white space delimited line:

Comment: Thanks so much!! May I ask why you didn't use a catch statement? I noticed the try but it doesn't have a catch. I added one, what would it be?

Comment: @JackieTowns He didn't use a `catch` block due to the try-with-resources way of opening the Scanner here: `try (Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in)) {`. Using this syntax, the JVM will automatically close the scnr when it's done without the need for manually doing it in a catch block.

Comment: Oh, and I just realized. Is there a reason to use the try statement to begin with?

Comment: Try is used only to dispose of the scanner object correctly. It is not strictly required, but you will get a warning if you don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-complicating this.  You just need one loop, which runs until the user enters 'n'.

Until that happens, ask the user to enter a number, read it in, and then ask if they want to continue.  Update the looping condition appropriately, and you're done:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> inputs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    try (Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        boolean valid = true;
        while (valid) {
            System.out.println("Enter some numbers: ");
            if (scnr.hasNextInt()) {
                inputs.add(scnr.nextInt());
            }
            System.out.println("Would you like to enter another?");
            String response = scnr.next();
            valid = response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("y");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(inputs);
}
```

**Produces output**

```
Enter some numbers: 
1
Would you like to enter another?
y
Enter some numbers: 
2
Would you like to enter another?
y
Enter some numbers: 
3
Would you like to enter another?
n
[1, 2, 3]
```